# .htaccess skip all rules if url matches

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to skip all rewrite URLs when specific URL matches. I want to open this page:

```
https://www.example.com/.well-known/pki-validation/godaddy.html
```

If `godaddy.html` matches the URL. Here is what i am doing:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "==/godaddy.html" 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.example.com/.well-known/pki-validation/godaddy.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/index.php
```

but it does not work. I have also tried the `[END]` flag, but when I write flag `[END]` it gives me 500 internal server error.

Comment: no only these two rules are there

Comment: Than which rule do you want to skip Or may clarify your problem.

Comment: I want to skip these rules 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-site.me
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-site.me/index.php
if this url https://www.my-site.me/.well-known/pki-validation/godaddy.html matches

Comment: That rule will be skipped anyway because condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-site.me` won't match since you are redirecting to `www.my-site.me/` in 1st rule

Comment: _Aside:_ Your condition: `RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "==/godaddy.html" ` would never match. Also, the `END` flag is only available on Apache 2.4+

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to stop rewriting, when the requested URL ends with `godaddy.html`, you can use a [`dash -`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) as the substitution

> Substitution of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the original URL-path that was matched by Pattern. The Substitution may be a:
>   ...
>   **- (dash)**
>       A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

```
RewriteRule godaddy.html$ - [L]
```